# Unable get Last Insert Id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have downloaded follwing code from one of Google Codes but problem is in getting Last Insert ID.

Please see in `run()` function

This method is used to run free-form SQL statements that can't be handled by the included delete, insert, select, or update methods. If no SQL errors are produced, this method will return the number of affected rows for DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements, or an associate array of results for SELECT, DESCRIBE, and PRAGMA statements.

```
<?php

    class db extends PDO {

        private $error;
        private $sql;
        private $bind;
        private $errorCallbackFunction;
        private $errorMsgFormat;
        public $lastid;
        public function __construct($dsn, $user = "", $passwd = "") {
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );

            try {
                parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }





        private function filter($table, $info) {
            $driver = $this->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
            if ($driver == 'sqlite') {
                $sql = "PRAGMA table_info('" . $table . "');";
                $key = "name";
            } elseif ($driver == 'mysql') {
                $sql = "DESCRIBE " . $table . ";";
                $key = "Field";
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '" . $table . "';";
                $key = "column_name";
            }

            if (false !== ($list = $this->run($sql))) {
                $fields = array();
                foreach ($list as $record)
                    $fields[] = $record[$key];
                return array_values(array_intersect($fields, array_keys($info)));
            }
            return array();
        }

        private function cleanup($bind) {
            if (!is_array($bind)) {
                if (!empty($bind))
                    $bind = array($bind);
                else
                    $bind = array();
            }
            return $bind;
        }

        public function insert($table, $info) {
            $fields = $this->filter($table, $info);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . implode($fields, ", ") . ") VALUES (:" . implode($fields, ", :") . ");";
            $bind = array();
            foreach ($fields as $field)
                $bind[":$field"] = $info[$field];
            return $this->run($sql, $bind);
        }

        public function run($sql, $bind = "") {
            $this->sql = trim($sql);
            $this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);
            $this->error = "";

            try {
                $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
                if ($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
                    if (preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("select", "describe", "pragma")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                        return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    elseif (preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("delete", "insert", "update")) . ") /i", $this->sql)) {
                       echo $this->lastInsertId();
                        return $pdostmt->rowCount();
                    }
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
                return false;
            }
        }




    }

    ?>
```

Code i use to Insert Record

```
    $insert = array(
        "userid" => 12345,
        "first_name" => "Bhavik",
        "last_name" => "Patel",
        "email" => "bhavik@sjmtechs.com",
        "password" => "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70"

   $db->insert("users",$insert);
    echo $db->lastid;
```

Comment: `implode("|", array("delete", "insert", "update"))` Oh god please why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `insert()` function, you've never set `$lastid`, so it never has the correct value. You'll need something like this:

Change this line in the `insert()` function:

```
return $this->run($sql, $bind);
```

To this:

```
$rows = $this->run($sql, $bind);
$this->lastid = $this->lastInsertId();
return $rows;
```

You should also be able to access the `lastInsertId()` from outside of the class, even without the above modifications, like so:

```
$db->insert("users",$insert);
echo $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: It's the count returned from `$pdostmt->rowCount();`.

Comment: Because your SQL query isn't correct or isn't inserting anything. Check the SQL query.

Comment: it is inserting . i checked in database

Comment: @ChetanPatel - Your column type must be an AUTOINCREMENT column type in order to get the next inserted ID. Is the column an AutoIncrement column?

Comment: I'm not talking about the SQL. I'm talking about the structure of the table. The column type must be set to autoincrement for it to work.

Comment: @ChetanPatel - Glad to hear it. If my post answered your question, please consider accepting it.