# Last Insert ID is not returning

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have following code for inserting data into database using PDO.

It inserts data into database but not return last inserted in ID.

here `userid` is primary key

```
  try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crud_demo', "username", "password");

        $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users(userid,first_name,last_name,email,password)
            VALUES(:userid,:first_name,:last_name,:email,:password)";

        $statement = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $bind = array(
            ":userid" => "bhavik",
            ":first_name" => "Bhavik",
            ":last_name" => "Patel",
            ":email" => "bhavitk@live.in",
            ":password" => "1234567"
        );
        $statement->execute($bind);
        echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

`$dbh->lastInsertId();` always return 0 whatever i insert value for userid

Comment: no it is not icnremental @FabioCosta

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable get Last Insert Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156133/unable-get-last-insert-id)

Comment: You are inserting your own value for your ID, so why do you need to get it back? You already know what it is, right?

Comment: @nickb it was also my question but there some problem so i asked again

Comment: if your primary key is varchar, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923366/getting-last-record-from-mysql). I also had same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lastInsertId()` only returns IDs automatically generated in an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. Your `PRIMARY KEY` is apparently a string (or at least you're inserting a string in it). Since you're inserting a known value, you don't actually need to find out the inserted ID — you've specified it yourself.

Comment: +1. `lastInsertId()` accept a `$name` parameter. Is it possible to specify `userid` if it's an integer type ? (Never tried, just thought about it)

Comment: `lastInsertId($name)` is used for databases like Postgresql. There is no `AUTO_INCREMENT` column modifier there, but you have sequences that implement this functionality, and as a side effect you can have multiple incremental values in the table, and you need to provide the name of the sequence whose last value you want.

Answer (score 5):

The `userid` doesn't have an `auto_increment` attribute in your database, so `lastInsertId()` will never return anything useful.

You can only `lastInsertId()` if your field is:

1. the primary key
2. not null
3. an integer type (int, bigint, etc.)
4. auto_increment

Answer (score 0):

first you need to check insert query.

if its run proper then use mysql function like mysql_insert_id().

if this function is run property then may be possible to mistake in your $dbh->lastInsertId()

this function.

Comment: Asker is using the PDO_MySQL extension, not ext/mysql. ext/mysql is [not recommended](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for future development. And, [`lastInsertId()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) is part of the PDO library, not a user-defined method.